# error C2244:'Stack<T>::operator=': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

Tags: c++

```
public:    
    Stack<T>&operator=(const Stack<int>& rlist);    
private:    
    int *top;    

template<class T>
Stack<T>& Stack<int>::operator=(const Stack<int>& rlist)    
{    
    if(this==&rlist)    
        return *this;    
    makeEmpty();    
    deepCopy(rlist);    
    return *this;    
}
```

I got error that says `error C2244:'Stack<T>::operator=': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration` and don't know where to fix....

Answer (score 2):

You specify `<int>` all over the place for some weird reason.  All of those should be `<T>`.

```
Stack<T>&operator=(const Stack<int>& rlist);
//                            ^^^^^

Stack<T>& Stack<int>::operator=(const Stack<int>& rlist) 
//             ^^^^^                       ^^^^^
```

Unless you are actually trying to specialize for when `T=int` (if so then your syntax is flawed), but based on the implementation of the assignment operator I don't think that's what you're attempting.